# How do I disable the login screen on XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu 11.10, but can't see how to disable the login screen. I'm pretty sure I set it to auto login during setup, but recently upgraded, and now it's asking for a password when I turn the machine on. Also, I've disabled "prompt for password on resume" but the password is still showing. Any ideas how to disable both of those passwords?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I feel your pain. 11.04 did have an easily accessible auto login setting. 11.10 took that away. To set autologin now you must edit lightdm.conf.  In terminal at the user prompt type...

```
~$ sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following line to the end and save...

```
autologin-user=YourDesiredAutoLoginUserName
```

To remove password on resume, right-click the system tray power icon then Preferences. This brings up the XFCE power manager (Alternatively you can navigate to XFCE/Settings/Settings Manager/Power Manager). Click Extended in the left pane. Uncheck `Lock screen when going for suspend/hibernate`.

The last place is XFCE/System/Users and Groups. If it's set "Password: Asked on login" you can change that but it's really not necessary.

Comment: I'm in Xfce 4.10 but did all that and still I'm asked for username and password after logging out...

Comment: Make sure you do this under the [SeatDefaults] section ;)

Comment: I desperately needed this answer!!

Comment: In addition to this user has to belong to autologin group. More info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Enabling_autologin

Answer (score 3):

To enable Auto Login:

- Add `autologin-user=YourDesiredAutoLoginUserName` to **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf**

Disable Prompt for Password on Resume:

- Uncheck 'Screen Locker' from Session and Startup